# Issues with installing the NVIDIA driver Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, nvidia

I want to install Docker NVIDIA packages on Ubuntu Desktop (Windows 10 Pro is a host OS). I do have Docker runnung and now I am trying to install the NVIDIA driver for Ubuntu.

After the following steps:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
```

I have this (after rebooting):

```
sarah@WIN-8BAACGLFG8Q:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Then I ran the same command on my host OS:

```
C:\Users\User>nvidia-smi
Thu Mar 17 22:15:45 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 461.92       Driver Version: 461.92       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX330      WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P0    N/A /  N/A |     64MiB /  2048MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After that, I thought that maybe versions have to match and tried to install nvidia-driver-460 on Ubuntu. Error remained.

Then I followed the solutions from [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/197141). Nothing changed.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67071102/11810933) didn't help either.

I also disabled Secure Boot. The same.

Comment: You use docker on WSL Ubuntu, did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @mashuptwice yes

Comment: Nvidia hardware is most likely not be visible in a VM, I'd expect there to be a VM-related display driver only, e.g. provided by the "guest additions" for Virtualbox (dunno what the corresponding thing is for VMWare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under WSL, you can't actually install a Linux video driver, since you don't have a video device in the first place.  Your Ubuntu WSL instance is actually a container itself, running in the WSL2 VM (that you can't access).  So just like you can't install a video driver into a Docker container, you can't install a video driver in WSL.

However, if your goal is to use the nVidia Docker images for GPU compute tasks, then Microsoft has enabled GPU compute in WSL2 *using the Windows nVidia driver*.  See [Enable NVIDIA CUDA on WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-cuda-in-wsl) for details.

You'll need at least Windows 10 21H2 (so very recent) or Windows 11.  You'll also want to have a very recent Windows nVidia driver installed.

While I haven't done it myself, [this Docker article](https://www.docker.com/blog/wsl-2-gpu-support-for-docker-desktop-on-nvidia-gpus/) covers using the nVidia Docker images in Docker Desktop and WSL2.

Comment: Thank You So Much!! I've been struggling with this for a whole week